# Long Processing time

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have access to a cluster and I was wondering if `NMinimize[]` with the `"Differential Evolution"` method could be used to parallel process an answer for faster computation? After some research it looks like this was brought up in 2004 with a conclusion that it would be too difficult. So have there been any updates that allows parallelization to be used with `NMinimize[]`?

If so, could you provide me with some examples?

Comment: Where _"it was brought up in 2004 with an conclusion that it would be too difficult."_?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I've exhausted mathematica documentation, google searches along with threads on this website. I'm now trying to reach out to the community

Comment: The title doesn't really match your question. Where is the syntax error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there have not been any significant changes since 2004 that would affect what you are asking about. It is also worth noting that `NMinimize` is not necessarily coded in the most efficient way possible, so it may not be the best solution compared to your own hand-written differential evolution (DE) code (to which you can, of course, easily add parallelism).

If you are interested, you can see [my own implementation of DE](https://github.com/oleksandrr/differential_evolution), written in Python. It is more efficient than *Mathematica*'s implementation and offers a choice of different mutation and selection operators, which make it more adaptable to different problems. It is not parallelized because my experience has been that DE and expensive objective functions are not a natural combination, but adding parallelization would be straightforward if you consider this a reasonable thing to do in your case.

There are quite a number of papers in the literature about parallel implementations of DE. This is not surprising because the algorithm is trivially parallelizable over objective function evaluations. But, none of the papers I have read adequately addresses the critical flaw, which is that DE simply performs a lot of objective function evaluations--often far more than methods developed in the 20 years since DE--relative to the progress it makes in minimizing the objective function value. Many of these evaluations result in poor solutions that are not accepted into the population, and therefore do not serve any useful purpose beyond speculative exploration of the parameter space. The venerable Nelder-Mead method is one of the most economical in terms of the amount of improvement per objective function evaluation, although it is not well suited for global minimization as it is basically a local method. There have been various attempts to incorporate local search into DE to try to improve the situation, but this is not straightforward without introducing additional tuning parameters, and also carries the risk of making the resulting algorithm too "greedy", which can compromise the ability of DE to avoid spurious local minima.

Comment: Thank you Oleksandr, very good answer! I'm moving away from DE for my optimization problem and more towards a multistart method with FindMinimum such that I can easily make use of parallelize.